# SQL not properly filtering on certain criteria

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having a bit of trouble with my MySQL query:

```
$statement = $conn->prepare
("SELECT * FROM ext where `approved` = 0 
and `account-type`= 2 
AND `ext-name` LIKE :search OR description LIKE :search");
```

The LIKE part of the query works--it does return entries corresponding with the right keywords. However, the entries it returns are of every `account-type` -- it's not filtering down to only ones with an `account-type` of 2.

I have a feeling this is something I'm doing wrong with the SQL statement, but in case it's something with my PHP, here's the full snippet:

```
    $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ext where `approved` = 0 and `account-type`= 2 AND `ext-name` LIKE :search OR description LIKE :search");
    $statement->bindValue(':search', "%{$keyword}%");
    $statement->execute();

    $exchanges = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use parenthesis :

```
SELECT * FROM ext 
where `approved` = 0 and `account-type`= 2 
AND (`ext-name` LIKE :search OR description LIKE :search)
```

Comment: Ah! I'd actually tried parenthesis but I must've been putting them in the wrong place. Thanks a bunch. I'll accept once the time elapses.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you miss parenthesis in last line:

```
AND `ext-name` LIKE :search OR description LIKE :search"
```

Without them query returns all rows matching `description LIKE :search`.

This is typical error -- if query doesn't return what you expect and you have `OR` in your
query you probably miss some parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You should use braces to express priority you want.

You probably mean:

```
SELECT * FROM ext where `approved` = 0 
 and `account-type`= 2 
 AND (`ext-name` LIKE :search OR description LIKE :search )
```

But actually condition is evaluated like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ext 
where ( `approved` = 0  and `account-type`= 2 AND `ext-name` LIKE :search )
 OR description LIKE :search
```